# Extract pattern from a column based on another column's value

Tags: python, pandas, extract

given two columns of a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'word': ['replay','replayed','playable','thinker','think','thoughtful', 'ex)mple'],
      'root': ['play','play','play','think','think','think', 'ex)mple']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['word','root'])
```

I'd like to extract the substring of column `word` that includes everything up to the end of the string in the corresponding column `root` or `NaN` if the string in `root` is not included in `word`. That is, the resulting dataframe would look as follows:

```
word       root    match
replay     play    replay
replayed   play    replay
playable   play    play
thinker    think   think
think      think   think
thoughtful think   NaN
ex)mple    ex)mple ex)mple
```

My dataframe has several thousand rows, so I'd like to avoid for-loops if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with `str.extract` in a `groupby`+`apply`:

```
import re
df['match'] = (df.groupby('root')['word']
                 .apply(lambda g: g.str.extract(f'^(.*{re.escape(g.name)})'))
               )
```

Or, if you expect few repeated "root" values:

```
import re
df['match'] = df.apply(lambda r: m.group()
                       if (m:=re.match(f'.*{re.escape(r["root"])}', r['word']))
                       else None, axis=1)
```

output:

```
         word   root   match
0      replay   play  replay
1    replayed   play  replay
2    playable   play    play
3     thinker  think   think
4       think  think   think
5  thoughtful  think     NaN
```

Comment: I get: `re.error: 'unbalanced parenthesis at position 7`. My hunch is it is due to special characters in the columns ```word``` or `root`. Unique characters in both columns are: `{'r', '!', 'e', 'u', 'i', 'K', '@', ')', 'j', 'p', '(', '<', 'I', 'N', '*', 'a', '|', 'm', '_', ' ', 'b', '}', 'w', '3', 'g', 'Z', 'h', 'o', '4', 'A', '1', 'O', 'M', 'y', 'E', 'k', 'S', 'l', '2', 'n', 'L'}`

Comment: @hyhno01 yes, you probably have a parenthesis in the root. Please check the update and please update your question to add an example of root for which it failed

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by mozway, the regex can also be pieced together, thankfully. A different application, that one might think would be commonly useful.

Here, there are two columns `full` and `tiny` with a third ... `context` being created.

`tiny` like `30 year old` (although these vary a lot, day, week, month, decade etc) was extracted from long content in the `full` string/column *(and then operated on to get just the integer in yet another column that doesn't matter for these purposes)*.

It was decided that more surrounding `context` instead of just the essential `tiny` string would be better and this solved that without needing to do intricate surgery on existing code.

```
df['context'] = df.groupby('tiny', group_keys=False)['full'].apply(
   lambda g: g.str.extract(
      r'\b(.{0,20}' + f'{re.escape(g.name)}' + r'.{0,20}\b)'
   )
)
```

To explain that regex:

`r'\b(.{0,20}' + f'{re.escape(g.name)}' + r'.{0,20}\b)'`

... it says basically for what's found in the column titled `tiny` on each row, find its match  over in the column named `full` but add up to 20 characters **before** it (stop short at a word boundary when necessary to avoid having a word cut off part way) and also add up to 20 characters **after** it, and likewise regarding the `\b`.

*`group_keys=False` is to avoid a 'FutureWarning' at Python 3.7*